# Not able to view Dagger generated classes source code in IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2

I'm having trouble seeing the generated dagger classes in my project. The app builds, dagger injects the classes just fine, etc. but I can't actually view the dagger classes in my IDE - they show up as red (indicating an error), and trying to step into the class while debugging and/or viewing the source code to see how they are doing things doesn't work.

Here's a sample project that doesn't work for me: https://github.com/erikcaffrey/Dagger2-MVP-Sample

All I did was pull it, run it, and then went to the `CategoryApplication` class and tried to see the source for the `DaggerAppComponent` class, but I am not able to.

For reference, here's what I see: [image: dagger class unavailable]

Some additional information: On other computers I do not have this problem (Windows 10, MacBook Pro #2) but my main development MacBook Pro if affected by this.  The dagger generated files exist in my project structure and I can view them manually - but ideally the IDE can pick these up and not show this as an error visually.  I am using Android Studio 3.1.4 but this was also occurring in older versions (not sure on the exact numbers though)

The sample project I am using has the following gradle dependencies setup:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
```

It doe snot use the android dagger components, nor the android support components, FWIW.

Update: I noticed that my Android Studio instance on my dev MacBook Pro does not list the dagger generated files in the app/build/generated/source/apt/ directory when viewing the project files in the 'Project' setting.  The files on the hard drive do exist, but they do not show up in the IDE...  so I doubt this is a dagger issue - just something wrong with the IDE not picking up these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this was not an issue on Android Studio 3.2 beta, so I figured it was a configuration issue.  I went ahead and uninstalled Android Studio and deleted *all* references to Android Studio from my machine and then reinstalled Android Studio 3.1.4.  The issue is no longer occurring.

Answer (score 1):

```
def daggerVer = 2.12 // or latest version

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I tried this and did not see a change in behavior, even after cleaning/building/rebuilding/etc.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file, add this line:

```
dependencies {

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'

}
```

which will make the generated sources visible in android studio.

Comment: The apt command is deprecated right? I used annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15' and this did not work - same behavior.